# Html input type image: don't stretch image

Tags: html, css, button, input

I have an input of type image. Is there a way to let the input cover the whole size of the parent div without stretching the image? Here an example with a 48x48 image. The result is a 300x300 image, but I would like that the image keep the original size while the background color should cover the whole div

```html
    <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
      <input type="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_submit.gif" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;border: solid 1px #a8a8a8;padding:1px 6px;cursor:pointer;width: 100%;">
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you change input to img?

Comment: yes you can try to check this out https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using as background image where you will be able make the image as per your requirement and the input will be full height & width. Check snippet.

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0px !important;
  background-image:url("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_submit.gif");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
  <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
    <input style="background-color: #f0f0f0;border: solid 1px #a8a8a8;padding:1px 6px;cursor:pointer;width: 100%;">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I need an input to submit a form (html is generated from a jsf page, see my edit)

Comment: In that case you need to apply css to input - check updated answer.

Comment: I would like the image to keep the original size (48x48) while the background color should cover the whole div

Comment: That will not be possible - input & image both will be same you can't target individual - second option you can try this as background image check snippet.

Comment: Yes, it did! The trick ist to use background-image:url("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_submit.gif"); Thx!

Answer (score 1):

At first set the width and height of the parent div and then use some css like below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="myImageParent">
  <input class="myImage" type="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_submit.gif" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myImageParent{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;   
    background-color: #eff;
}

.myImage{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;   
}
```

See the demo here:  http://www.cssdesk.com/JCw9M

Answer (score 0):

The image originally is small so when stretch it will be broken anyway. I think you could use svg instead [svg MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image)

Comment: I don't want to stretch the image :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by change width of 100% to 10% in the input tag.

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_submit.gif" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;border: solid 1px #a8a8a8;padding:1px 6px;cursor:pointer;width: 10%;">
</div>
```

Or Remove width, height from Div and width from input tag

```
<div>
  <input type="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_submit.gif" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;border: solid 1px #a8a8a8;padding:1px 6px;cursor:pointer;">
</div>
```

Or add This one

```
<input type="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_submit.gif" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;border: solid 1px #a8a8a8;padding:1px 6px;cursor:pointer;">
```

Comment: I could, but I need the background color to  fill the whole div

Comment: background-color: #f0f0f0; this color?

Comment: Please Check last one it is ok for you with background color also

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the image to be of original size and background color should cover the whole div, then it is not possible with input type image, but you can try this:

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
  <button type="submit" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;border: solid 1px #a8a8a8;padding:1px 6px;cursor:pointer;width: 100%;height:100%;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_submit.gif" />
  </button>
</div>
```